# $form->input to create a radio button using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am using jQuery and CakePHP for my application.

In my application with the data that I have saved in the database, for example if the Field type column is text then I am generating a text box in my code using $form->input();

If it is a dropdown box, I am generating it using:

```
echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'],
    array('id'=>$r['Attribute']['id'],'name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],
        'options' => array(1,2,3,4,5)));
```

Now I have a field of type "Radio button". I am trying to create the radio box in CakePHP.
Is it possible... If so how?

Answer (score 4):

Using `FormHelper::input()`, you can specify the type of field you want by setting the [`type`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options) option:

```
echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'id' => $r['Attribute']['id'],
    'name' => $r['Attribute']['label'],
    'options' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
));
```

Unlike calling `FormHelper::radio()` directly, the input's label and validation errors will be rendered.

Comment: And a bout boolean radio? where input database value is type boolean but cake (or PDO) shows 'f' and 't'?  I can't get  te boolean value to set the correct radio option (on edit.cpt).

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
$options=array('M'=>'Male','F'=>'Female');
$attributes=array('legend'=>false);
echo $this->Form->radio('gender',$options,$attributes);
```

Try with your attributes

Comment: And a bout boolean radio? where input database value is type boolean but cake (or PDO) shows 'f' and 't'?  I can't get  te boolean value to set the correct radio option (on edit.cpt).

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'],
    array('id'=>$r['Attribute']['id'],'name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],
         'type'=>'radio',
         'options' => array(1=>'male',2=>'female',3=>'Others')
    ));
```